# send command to remote machine after using expect

Tags: linux, expect

Hi i would like to collect some info about process from remote machine
and after it, kill the process.

i wrote a script using expect, i succeed to connect to the remote machine 
but i can't send other commands, like 'who' and get the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no aaa@1.2.4.5
expect "Password:"
send "aaa1"
interact
send "who\r"
```

can someone please advise?
basically i'm new with expect so i guess it something simple that i'm probably missing.

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `expect` for this.  You need key-based SSH login.  You can achieve this by running `ssh-copy-id aaa@1.2.4.5` just once to set it up, then after that you should be able to just run:

```
ssh aaa@1.2.4.5 who
```

And it should not prompt for a password, because it will be using your SSH keys.  Of course, if you never had SSH keys before you may need to run ssh-keygen or similar before ssh-copy-id.

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed it out, maybe you simply don't need expect. If you still want to use expect, something like this may work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect                                                               

spawn ssh username@host                                                 
expect "*?assword:*"                                                            
send -- "yourPasswordHere\r"                                                    
send -- "\r"                                                                    
expect eof
```

expect PATTERN waits until PATTERN matches. In your case the pattern "Password:" is not found, but a more permissive pattern "*?assword:*" will be found. Usually your ssh client will ask you this in the form of:

```
username@host's password:
```